# how to create a TCustomControl that behaves like Tpanel?

Tags: delphi, custom-component, tpanel, tcustomcontrol

how do I create a TCustomControl that will behave like Tpanel? eg MyCustomComponent, that I can drop components in like labels, images etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick is this piece of code in TCustomPanel:

```
constructor TCustomPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ControlStyle := [csAcceptsControls {, ... } ];
//...
end;
```

There are many more VCL controls you can descend from that have `csAcceptsControls` in their `ControlStyle` property.

If you want to do this in your own controls, but do not descend from such a VCL control, then you should do something like this:

1. Override the Create constructor
2. Add `csAcceptsControls` to the `ControlStyle` property

Like this sample code:

```
//MMWIN:MEMBERSCOPY
unit _MM_Copy_Buffer_;

interface

type
  TMyCustomControl = class(TSomeControl)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;


implementation

{ TMyCustomControl }

constructor TMyCustomControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls {, ...} ];
//...
end;


end.
```

--jeroen