# Delphi - Making a user control a container without inheriting from an existing container

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I need to make a control a conainter(that holds other controls at design and run time) similiar a TPanel, without inheriting from the custom panel or a similar control, how do i tell my control that its suppose to contain stuff???

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278752/how-to-create-tcustomcontrol-behave-like-tpanel and also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374451/how-do-i-create-a-custom-control-with-a-sub-panel-that-accepts-other-controls-at

Answer (score 7):

You need to add the **csAcceptsControls** style to your control's ControlStyle property.  Something like this in the constructor of your control class:

```
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls];
```

You will almost certainly want to set other **ControlStyle** properties also though so don't just take this verbatim but research the **ControlStyle** flags and decide which are appropriate in your case.